# Highchart - Array of array of categories

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, column-chart

Is it possible in HighChart to split the xAxis one level more?

I basically need to merge these 4 graphs in one graph with the same yAxis, and each A,B,C,D needs to be a tick.

[image: 1]
[http://i.imgur.com/obiIstC.png](https://i.imgur.com/obiIstC.png)

xAxis categories for each graph:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4']
},
```

Basically, is there a workaround to set xAxis categories as an Array of Arrays or Objects ? This would do nice:

```
xAxis:{
    categories: [
        {'A': ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4']},
        {'B': ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4']},
        {'C': ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4']},
        {'D': ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4']},
    ]
}
```

or

```
xAxis:{
    categories: [
        ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4'],
        ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4'],
        ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4'],
        ['Value1','Value2','Value3', 'Value4']
    ]
}
```

In order to achieve something like this:

[image: 2]
[http://i.imgur.com/yKTI1VR.png](https://i.imgur.com/yKTI1VR.png)

PS: Please excuse my poor paint skills.

Comment: A bit hard to see how you intend for this to work. Is that several columns within one x category (all between 0 and 1)? Either way, perhaps this: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/4dccq/light/

Comment: @Ondkloss That fiddle only partially solves my problem. For your example to work, I need to split every tick (from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, etc.) in 4 more sub-ticks.

Comment: And is that really a problem? That can be solved in a handful of ways with categories or values or ticklabels...

Comment: @Ondkloss I don't think you understood my problem. I'll update the question in about 1 hour, with better explanations.

Comment: You most probably need [grouped-categories](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin for 3D charts, which is unfortunately not supported. You can workaround this by playing with options: http://jsfiddle.net/92btfLL8/ - but after enabling legend it will show up some problems. And I think that @Ondkloss was referring something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/144/